# How To Set Up Shure BLX4/SM58 And What Other Components Are Needed

Tags: microphones

So I’ve just bought a Shure BLX4/SM58 but am stuck when it comes to setting up. And of course it does not work by itself and needs some sort of stereo or PA system to make the sound work, so what cheap option do u suggest for this and how to overall set it up. Any information would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but... you bought 300 quid's worth of kit without having the faintest idea what to do next???

Comment: @Tetsujin well, some people will spend £300 (or even £3,000) on an item of clothing, and then never wear it because they don't like the colour! Humans are not renowned for being logical.

Comment: I wonder why SE "bumped" this old question...  The main question is vague and the secondary question is an off-topic product recommendation request.  Hopefully OP figured it out in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

The channel-matching between mic and receiver is fully described in the printed manual.  If you've lost yours, here's a download.

https://pubs.shure.com/guide/BLX/en-US

Yes, you'll need a PA system to run it through.   Same as you would if you'd bought a mic with a cable.  They come in all sizes!  Maybe the venue you'll be performing in has one that they'll let you plug into.  What sort of work are you thinking of doing?

Comment: Thanks for the info, so as a cheap alternative could I connect the BLX4 receiver into a stereo speaker via an aux lead for the time being until upgrading to a PA having blown budget on mic itself as I can control the volume on that or do u know of an affordable PA? All this is for a band I have started with my mates which we upload covers and originals on to YouTube.

Comment: If you're only recording, why did you buy a wireless mic?

Comment: It was only cause I was recommended by a friend to buy this as our WHOLE band is electric so it would save space and could also be used for performances outside of recording where we would be required to bring our own equipment, so would an aux Cable be ok?!

Comment: Not sure how having a mic, receiver, power supply and cable saves space over having just a mic and cable!  But yes, you can connect it into just about anything which includes an amplifier and a speaker.

Comment: JKidd: it might help if you added more context. So you sing in a band? Do you have a rehearsal room? Does that rehearsal room have a PA system, or any general-purpose amps (keyboard amp etc.) that have spare inputs? What kinds of amps are your bandmates using?